# Displaying columns as rows SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below tables:

Corporate table:

```
CorporateId    DirectorId    ManagerId     SalesId
```

---

```
  1              1              1           1  
  2              2              2           3
  3              3              4           5
```

Employee table:

```
EmployeeId      FirstName    LastName
```

---

```
  1               Tim         Sarah           
  2               Tom         Paulsen           
  3               Tam         Margo
  4               Eli         Lot
  5               Ziva        Lit
```

I want to display, for one corporate,the names of the Director, Manager and Sales in rows.  Example with corporate 3:

```
EmployeeId      FirstName    LastName
```

---

```
  3               Tam         Margo
  4               Eli         Lot
  5               Ziva        Lit
```

How can I do that?  I know how to display rows as columns using pivot, but unsure if pivot can be used here also.
Any help please?

Comment: If you know how to pivot then you simply need to join the pivoted data to your `Employee` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may join the two tables as the following:

```
SELECT E.EmployeeId, E.FirstName, E.LastName
FROM Employee E JOIN Corporate C
ON  E.EmployeeID IN (C.DirectorId ,C.ManagerId ,C.SalesId)
WHERE C.CorporateId=3
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/KkzGYvGN).

Answer (score 1):

You can first un-pivot your rows into columns by using *cross apply*, after which you simply join the pivoted rows to your *employee* table:

```
select e.*
from corporate c
cross apply (
  select EmployeeId from (
    values (Directorid), (ManagerId), (SalesId)
  )r(EmployeeId)
)r
join employee e on e.EmployeeId = r.EmployeeId
where c.CorporateId = 3;
```